# Behavior of select and behaviour of =,IN, Exists in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

When I run the below two queries I get the same result:

```
select * from bambam where name in(select name from bambam1 where bambam1.name=bambam.name);

select * from bambam where name =(select name from bambam1 where bambam1.name=bambam.name);
```

My first question here what is difference between `IN` and `=` ?

My second question is when I am running the `select` part of sub query (`select name from bambam1 where bambam1.name=bambam.name`) I am getting the error below, Why?

> Error at line 1
>
> ORA-00904: "BAMBAM"."NAME": invalid identifier

I have 2 tables as below:

```
BAMBAM:

NAME DATE1    
---- ---------
gha  07-MAY-16

gh   12-DEC-12

abc       

BAMBAM1

NAME
----
gh  
abc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between `IN` and `=` as long as you are 100% sure the subquery always returns at most one row. `IN` works like this:  `where x in (1, 2, 3)` means - by definition! - the same thing as `where x = 1 or x = 2 or x = 3`. In particular, if the list in parentheses has exactly one element:  `where x in (1)` means exactly the same thing as `where x = 1`.

Also, when the subquery returns no results, then both the `IN` query and the `=` query return no rows. This is what you should expect for the `IN` query. For the `=` query Oracle should complain (throw an error), but instead Oracle (the company) decided to simply return no results in that case as well, and not to throw an error. However, if the subquery returns MORE than one result, then the `IN` query will return as many rows as there are results from the subquery for **each** value of `name`, while the `=` query will show an error message.

So, for the name `gha` in `bambam`, the subquery returns no results, so both "larger" queries return no row for `gha`. For `gh` the subquery returns exactly one result, `gh` - so the "larger" or "outer" queries both return `gh`. And the same with `abc`.

For your other question, are the tables really EXACTLY as you show them? One is bambam and the other bambam2, but in the query you refer to bambam1? If so, you have your answer. If not, please pay attention to details.   Good luck!

Comment: I have corrected the table name as bambam1,Here subquery returns 2 result is i am not wrong as 2 names are common 'gh' abd 'abc', Still i am not getting why = and IN behaving like same, I am getting 2 row selected in both case. Please can you also describe why subquery as a standalone is showing error. I am a beginner in SQL so not getting exactly whats the issue with subquery.

Comment: Dave answered the question about subquery very clearly. Just read it by itself:  `select name form bambam1 where bambam1.name = bambam.name`. To process this, Oracle (or SQL in general) FIRST looks at the "from" clause: FROM BAMBAM1. Then any column names you use must be from the tables listed in the FROM clause. You can't get around this by adding the table name: bambam.name is a column in the table bambam, and bambam was not mentioned in the FROM clause. If you say "select ... from bambam1, bambam where..." then it will be OK, but now the "select" should show from which table you select name

Comment: When you use the same "select" as a subquery in a larger query, you are OK, because in that case the tables named in the FROM clause of the larger query are visible from within the subquery.  For the IN portion I will edit my answer to add more detail.

Comment: thank a lot for explaining, i got the answer. @mathguy

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question:  If you run just this query:

```
select name from bambam1 where bambam1.name=bambam.name
```

`bambam` is an unknown identifier because it doesn't appear in the query as the name or alias of a row source.

When you run the full query, it resolves `bambam` from the main FROM clause.  When you pull the subquery out on its own, that context is gone.

Comment: Right... I misread the question in the original post (so badly, I thought your explanation was wrong). I didn't understand the OP was running the subquery by itself, as a stand-alone query! Good catch. I just went for the obvious (which "obvious" had nothing to do with the error message!)